# What is the difference between ServletContext and ServletActionContext

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, actioncontext

Please tell me what is the difference between `ServletActionContext` and `ServletContext`?
`ServletContext` is shared among all the servlets and actions, while `ServletActionContext` is specific to an action or is that also shared among all the actions?

Comment: `ServletActionContext` is not part of standard JSP/Servlet specs , it is provided by Struts, it provides a way to access to web objects like servlet parameters, request attributes and things like the HTTP session.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I want to know whether ServletActionContext is shared by all the actions or specific to an action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are different things. `ServletContext` is a servlet related, `ActionContext` is Struts 2 action related, `ServletActionContext` extends `ActionContext` but in major it's an utility class.

If you want to know [what is the actioncontext](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/what-is-the-actioncontext.html).

Comment: Thanks. I have another doubt, Is ServletActionCotext shared by all actions or is that specific to one action?

Comment: @user1147070 I don't understand your question, `ActionContext` is created per action, and it's threadlocal, means not accessible by other actions/threads.

Answer (score 0):

**ServletConfig Object:**

- It is ONE per our Servlet class object
- Servlet container creates this either during server startup or during the deployment of web app based on Servlet configuration done in web-xml file
- It is the object of servlet container supplied java class that impleents java.servlet.ServletCongfig(I).